# Can @WithuserDetails inject @AuthenticationPrinciple during controller tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is my Test

```
@Test
@WithUserDetails(USER_USERNAME)
void shouldCreateVote_whenPost() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(
            post("/vote")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(VOTE_CREATION_ADRIANO)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    Mockito.verify(voteService, times(1))
            .addVote(refEq(BASIC_USER_ENTITY), refEq(VOTE_CREATION_ADRIANO));
}
```

It fails because AuthentificationPrinciple is null

```
         Body = {"status":400,"message":"Cannot invoke \"com..grad.restaurant.security.AuthenticatedUser.getUser()\" because \"authenticatedUser\" is null","timeStamp":1629649641723}
```

Here is the Controller I am testing

```
    @PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@AuthenticationPrincipal AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser,
                   @RequestBody @Valid VoteCreationDTO voteCreationDTO,
                   BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throwExceptionIfBindingResultHasErrors(bindingResult);
    }
    voteService.addVote(authenticatedUser.getUser(), voteCreationDTO);
}
```

Comment: Verify that the method actually works in production (it probably does, but you should say you checked, if you did) and post the whole test class with annotations and everything -- this is basically guaranteed to be a problem with your test configuration.

Comment: @neofelis you were right, I changed my implementation of UserDetailsService for Tests and it's working. Thank you